# Как определить корень у имени?

Tags: словообразование

Столкнулась со сложностью разбора имен по составу. Например, Наталья. Корень Натал- или Нат- (ведь есть же сокращения). Как быть с именами: Татьяна, Валентин, Александр и др.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, разбирать любое неславянское имя иначе как корень и окончание не имеет никакого смысла.
Предположим, что корень у Натальи Нат-. Тогда получается, что -аль суффикс. Ещё выходит в русском языке есть суффиксы -андр, -ентин, -тьян, которые используются только в одном слове, и больше нигде. Звучит как-то глупо.

Я считаю, что полное имя, и имя сокращённое - это разные слова, с разными корнями. Иначе, если уж идти до конца, то надо выделить общий корень и среди имён Иван-Джон(англ)-Юкка(фин).

Comment: Согласна полностью.